# Are older versions of iWorks available?

Tags: iwork

Can I download a version of iWorks from Apple that will work with 10.6.8 before I upgrade to 10.7 or above.  I have a lot of Appleworks files I want to convert before I upgrade the system.

Answer (score 1):

As is not available on Apple websites, I found this that seems to work.

1. Visit this [Softpedia link](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Business/Apple-iWork-06.shtml) to download a free trial of iWork ’09.
2. Click **Download**, and then click **External Mirror 1**.
3. Double-click on the downloaded file. This will open up a window with a couple of files inside.
4. Double-click **Install iWork ’09 Trial** and follow the installation instructions.
5. After installation, close out the install windows and wait a few minutes for your Mac to recognize the newly-installed apps.
6. Next, open up the **App Store** app and click on the **Updates** tab at the top. You should see updates for Pages, Numbers and Keynote.
7. If you don’t see updates for these apps yet, close out of the App Store and wait a few minutes before opening it back up.